# Alexa skill state not changing with SessionEndedRequest

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm using alexa-sdk in Node.js. I have an Alexa skill with 4 different states persisted to DynamoDB. At the end of each interaction, I need the state to change to a READY state. At the end of each handler, I have a SessionEndedRequest where I set my state as follows:

```
this.state = States.READY;
this.emit(':saveState', true);
```

When the skill launches with READY state, I jump from state to state using:

```
this.handler.state = States.COMM;
this.emitWithState('NewSession');
```

I have NewSession in each handler.

My problem is that the state is not being reset when the user stops using the skill. I need it to go back to READY.

Can someone tell me what I need to do to accomplish that? Thanks.

Comment: I think that SessionEndedRequest is only triggered when the user doesn't say anything. In that case, I need to set the state after a user response. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have here:

```
this.state = States.READY;
this.emit(':saveState', true);
```

Won't set the state of Alexa app because the state key exists on the handler object, you will have to do

```
this.handler.state = States.READY;
this.emit(':saveState', true);
```

Let me know if this solves your problem. Thanks.